# Will journals that do not explicitly require it reject an author contribution statement?

Tags: publications, authorship

CRediT statements and other author contribution statements are becoming increasingly common ([[1]](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/leap.1210), [[2]](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/credit-author-statement)), but are not required by all journals. To prevent authorship disputes and foster transparency, it might be a good idea to include such a statement nevertheless. Hence my question: will a journal that does not explicitly require a contribution statement still accept and publish it if I add one voluntarily? Or will they remove it from the paper to ensure uniform style across their journal?

(Of course, one can simply try this with every journal and see what happens, but sorting out all the contributions in a long paper with many authors might involve significant work and discussions. So one would likely only want to do this if chances are high that the statement is actually published in the end.)

Comment: No one here can answer for all journals. But I doubt that a journal would just remove it without agreement.

Comment: There are journals that explicitly make such statements [optional](https://journals.aps.org/prl/authors/byline-addresses-footnotes-acknowledgments-statements-about-authors-h22).